# How to delete specific rows in a table view cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, rows, edit

I am using a table view which consists of three sections. User can delete the rows for third section. But while I am using table view delegate method for deleting rows ,It is affecting for other sections. So how could I overcome from this problem?

Here is my code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
      numbers.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)    
      tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
```

Comment: share relevant code here

Comment: Do you use IndexPath for identify, which section have you selected?

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
      numbers.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)    
      tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
  }

Comment: @Bhagabata add it to question.

Comment: @Vlad , Cell should be deleted for third section not for all sections .

Comment: Quick update : I need a custom delete button image ,So Ian using below method

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let remove = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "      ") { action, indexPath in


        print("delete button tapped")
    }

    remove.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Delete")!)

    return [remove]
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to restrict editing to section 2 implement `canEditRowAt` (code is Swift 3+)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return indexPath.section == 2
}
```

Or add a check

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete && indexPath.section == 2 {
      numbers.remove(at: indexPath.row)    
      tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
```

Comment: So @Bhagabata should use method one if he desires to inhibit all editing for those sections and method 2 if he just wants to prevent deletion.

Comment: Quick update : I am using below method for requirement

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let remove = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "      ") { action, indexPath in


        print("delete button tapped")
    }

    remove.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Delete")!)

    return [remove]
}

Comment: But I need a custom delete button instead of default delete.Csn anybody help me out ??

Answer (score 0):

correct way of doing this is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return indexPath.section == 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
   if editingStyle == .delete && indexPath.section == 2
   {
      yourArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
      yourtable.reloadData()
   }
}
```

Comment: If I select rows for section 1 or 2 ,It should not be delete

Answer (score 0):

In function with `forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath` you have `IndexPath` value.

It contains `.section`. So, you can simply check, which section have you selected and then do or not do deleting.

To delete rows for specific section:

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes ,I have used that condition but what is happening ,If i deleteing other rows for section 1 & 2 ,those are not deleting which is good but if I come back to the third section these rows are also not deleting .If I am doing revere it is working fine

Comment: @Bhagabata I think the problem in your line numbers.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row). You are selecting row, not full indexPath value, which also contains section info. Use other func.

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let remove = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "      ") { action, indexPath in


        print("delete button tapped")
    }

    remove.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Delete")!)

    return [remove]
}

Comment: @Bhagabata what is it?:) btw, you got an answer. I had same idea, but Mr. Vadian was faster:)

Comment: yea vandian nailed it :)